# Streaming Data from C++ to Python Inference Time Reduction

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning

I'm working on testing a neural network model on hardware and have the hardware code in C++ and model code in Python.

When I execute the Python code to run inference on a single streaming data point, the time for inference is about 2.5 seconds. 
But, if I execute inference on 200+ streaming data points, the average time for inference drops down to 0.10 seconds for each data point.

Is there a reason why inference runs so much faster basically for any number of points GREATER than 1? Is it because the GPU needs time to warm up or something?

Also, how can I take advantage of this when executing the Python script from my C++? I don't want to just call the Python script each time but rather emulate that I'm calling multiple streaming points. I'm currently thinking of using system() calls or Py_Initialize() from C++, but I feel that would still be calling inference on a single point at each time, so therefore I'm always running with the slowest inference.

Comment: neural networks are efficient when you are batch processing input data.time taken wont increase linearly with  increase in the input data.so if 1 data takes 1 sec to infer, 10 data points may take 2-3 seconds but not 10 seconds because of vectorisation.

Comment: There are too many possibilities: but basicly instantiations take time. If you use GPU - you have to initiate it, compile kernels, transfer data, etc...